# Advance Queue sample in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g, queue

I am looking for an end to end example in Advanced Queueing in Oralce 10G. I am in the process of understanding Adv Queuing i would like to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_demo.htm#i1007863) could be of use?

Comment: next question...

(attempted advanced queueing joke)